# How to set left and right paddings for UISearchController searchBar?

Tags: ios, swift, uisearchbar, uisearchcontroller

I'm using system searchBar via UISearchController in my Swift app. What is the correct way to set left and right padding to searchTextField? I need paddings for searchTextField itself, **not** just for text inside the field

I tried to set searchFieldBackgroundPositionAdjustment property(https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uisearchbar/1624320-searchfieldbackgroundpositionadj), but it doesn't change anything.

Here is a piece of code

```
    let searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
    navigationItem.searchController = searchController
    navigationItem.hidesSearchBarWhenScrolling = true
    definesPresentationContext = true
    
    searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
    searchController.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = false
    
    let textField = searchController.searchBar.searchTextField
    textField.font = UIFont(name: "AvenirNext-Regular", size: 16.0)

    // doesn't work
    searchController.searchBar.searchFieldBackgroundPositionAdjustment = UIOffset(horizontal: 100, vertical: 0)
```

See on screenshot what I'm trying to achive - make searchBar width equals to tabs panel in the bottom.

[image]

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
    let searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
           navigationItem.searchController = searchController
           navigationItem.hidesSearchBarWhenScrolling = true
           definesPresentationContext = true
           
           searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
           searchController.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = false
           
           let textField = searchController.searchBar.searchTextField
           textField.font = UIFont(name: "AvenirNext-Regular", size: 16.0)

         
        let directionalMargins = NSDirectionalEdgeInsets(top: 0, leading: 40, bottom: 0, trailing: 40)
        searchController.searchBar.directionalLayoutMargins = directionalMargins
        self.present(searchController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

searchFieldBackgroundPositionAdjustment is used to set the offset of the search text field background in the search bar and not for search bar margin.

Comment: hi, this does not change anything for some reason, the search field still stays the same

Comment: I have updated the answer with full code. It is working as expected for me.

Comment: I'm surprised you manually call `self.present(searchController)` - if it is set to navigationItem - why would we need it? a bit weird case.

Comment: To check if it works or not, I wrote this code for testing purpose where I was presenting searchController on the click of a button.

Comment: hi, thanks for reply! I tried code from updated answer and unfortunately the position and width of searchBar did not changed. Btw I also updated the question(added screenshot)

Comment: yeah maybe it deals with a fact that it gets shown automatically when the user scrolls down, this is a standard usage tho...